# Add mean to stacked bar ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

###### Current output

I have a series of bar plots, here's an example:

[image]

##### Problem

I would like to add a mean for the ellenberg values to the plot below the bars, i.e. y=-1. I'm not sure how to calculate it using a tally format.

##### This is my code:

#### EDIT: update code. I now have a column with the mean values

```
plotList <- list()
j = 1
for (df in ellenCatTab){
  dfName <- names(ellenCatTab)[j]
  j = j + 1

    col_means <- colMeans(df[,5:31], na.rm=TRUE)
    col_meansdf <- stack(col_means)
    col_meansdf <- as.data.table(col_meansdf)
    col_meansdf[, c('Q', 'Year') := tstrsplit(col_meansdf$ind, "_", fixed=TRUE)][]
    col_meansdf$Q <- sub('X', 'Q', col_meansdf$Q)
    col_meansdf$Q <- as.factor(col_meansdf$Q)
    col_meansdf$Year <- as.factor(col_meansdf$Year)
    col_meansdf[is.na(col_meansdf)] <- 0
    col_meansdf <- col_meansdf[,c(1,3,4)]
  
  df = df[,5:31]
  tidy <- df %>%
    gather(key='Quadrat', value='Ellenberg')
  tidy <- na.omit(tidy)
  tally <- tidy %>%
    count(Quadrat, Ellenberg)
  
  
  tally$Ellenberg <- as.factor(tally$Ellenberg)
  tally <- as.data.table(tally)
  tally[, c('Q', 'Year') := tstrsplit(tally$Quadrat, "_", fixed=TRUE)][]
  tally$Q <- sub('X', 'Q', tally$Q)
  tally$Q <- as.factor(tally$Q)
  tally <- left_join(tally, col_meansdf, by=c("Q"="Q", "Year"="Year"))
  tally$values[duplicated(tally$values)] <- NA

  
  stacked <- ggplot(tally, aes(fill=Ellenberg, y=n, x=Quadrat)) +
    geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity') +
    ggtitle(dfName) +
    labs(x='Year', y='Number of Plants') +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=labels) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colLegend) +
    theme_classic() +
    facet_wrap(~ Q, nrow=1, scales='free_x')
  
  #plotList[[dfName]]

  # ggsave(plot=stacked,
  #        file=paste0(dfName, '_stacked.png'),
  #        limitsize=FALSE,
  #        width=250, height=200, units='mm')
}
```

##### Example of the data frame

I have removed my data, but if you'd like to find a better solution I can re-add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by making a separate data frame and then performing a left_join. Then adding the label as a Geom_text().

```
plotList <- list()
j = 1
for (df in ellenCatTab){
  dfName <- names(ellenCatTab)[j]
  j = j + 1

    col_means <- colMeans(df[,5:31], na.rm=TRUE)
    col_meansdf <- stack(col_means)
    col_meansdf <- as.data.table(col_meansdf)
    col_meansdf[, c('Q', 'Year') := tstrsplit(col_meansdf$ind, "_", fixed=TRUE)][]
    col_meansdf$Q <- sub('X', 'Q', col_meansdf$Q)
    col_meansdf$Q <- as.factor(col_meansdf$Q)
    col_meansdf$Year <- as.factor(col_meansdf$Year)
    col_meansdf[is.na(col_meansdf)] <- 0
    col_meansdf <- col_meansdf[,c(1,3,4)]
    col_meansdf$values <- round(col_meansdf$values, digits=2)
  
  df = df[,5:31]
  tidy <- df %>%
    gather(key='Quadrat', value='Ellenberg')
  tidy <- na.omit(tidy)
  tally <- tidy %>%
    count(Quadrat, Ellenberg)
  
  
  tally$Ellenberg <- as.factor(tally$Ellenberg)
  tally <- as.data.table(tally)
  tally[, c('Q', 'Year') := tstrsplit(tally$Quadrat, "_", fixed=TRUE)][]
  tally$Q <- sub('X', 'Q', tally$Q)
  tally$Q <- as.factor(tally$Q)
  tally <- left_join(tally, col_meansdf, by=c("Q"="Q", "Year"="Year"))
  #tally$values[duplicated(tally$values)] <- NA

  
  stacked <- ggplot(tally, aes(fill=Ellenberg, y=n, x=Quadrat)) +
    geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity') +
    ggtitle(dfName) +
    labs(x='Year', y='Number of Plants') +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=labels) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colLegend) +
    theme_classic() +
    facet_wrap(~ Q, nrow=1, scales='free_x') +
    expand_limits(y=-0.5) +
    geom_text(
      label=tally$values, y=-1, color='red') +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-1, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25),
                       labels=expression("Mean", "0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25")) +
    theme(axis.text.y=element_text(colour=c('red', 'black', 'black','black','black','black', 'black'))) +
    theme(axis.ticks=element_line(colour=c('white', 'black', 'black','black','black','black', 'black'))) 
   plot(stacked)
  
  #plotList[[dfName]]

  # ggsave(plot=stacked,
  #        file=paste0(dfName, '_stacked.png'),
  #        limitsize=FALSE,
  #        width=250, height=200, units='mm')
}
```